# A C code beautifier that does *nothing* by default?

Tags: c, code-beautification

I'm fixing up a large, old, crufty project and want to introduce broad changes carefully, both because it will cause merge problems and because the old, crufty project contributors will get upset. At this point I just want to fix the indentation. Braces, comments... leave them all be for now.

Every tool I've tried (bcpp, uncrustify and GNU indent) all have their own ideas about how code should be formatted and I have to spend a lot of time figuring out how to turn them off, if they can be turned off. I also tried the Universal Indent GUI to configure them, but they still reformatted things I didn't ask for.

I need a C code beautifier that by default does *nothing*. Everything feature has to be turned on. Alternatively, I need a config file for one of the C beautifiers which turns everything off.

Answer (score 2):

I wish there was a tool that behaved like you describe. We gave up on using code formatting tools in our projects because the formatting changes they enforced annoyed developers far more than we annoyed each other with our own formatting quirks.

For indentation, in particular, most editors have functions to just indent without otherwise formatting, and you probably have one set up like you want it already. If your favorite editor has a batch mode, then that is probably your best option.

For example, vim has the [cindent](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html) feature, which after [configured as you wish](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values) can be invoked at the command line as `vim MyFile.cpp -c "%normal ==" -c "wq"`

If even that is too structured, you could try using retab or the [super retab](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1592) macros.

Answer (score 0):

The 'gc' code beautifier would do what you want, especially with the `-no-output-`option.

It can be downloaded from:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcgreatcode/?source=typ_redirect

Comment: `gc -file-foo.c -no-output-` did nothing. `gc -file-foo.c` reformatted the code like all the rest (with a very odd style, too) *and* changed the file permissions to write-only (?!) *and* pooped a banner in the file. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: re-route the output to a new file, so the original file is unchanged.   The source code is available as a .zip file, so you could unpack the .zip file, make any changes you would like, for instance if no parameters, other than the input file name, to always output the new file to /dev/NULL or to /tmp/samename as input file.

Comment: If I wanted to do *nothing* to my code I just wouldn't run gc! The point is to be able to turn features on one at a time.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I have tried this:  `./GC -no-output- -file-indent.c` for the file indent.c.   It makes no changes to the indent.c file   you could put the `-no-output-` parameter into the `GC.cfg` file and then GC will do nothing.  That can be overridden by command line parameters,

Comment: to modify the GC utility to produce files that contain the desired permissions.   in source file out.c, function: `writefile()`  line 254, modify the call to `chmod()` so the second parameter is something like: `0666`

Comment: This is so far off base it's getting weird.

Answer (score 0):

[Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net) (Astyle) appears to only adjust the indentation by default.

It has options for braces and comments.